how to change the icon for custom fieldtype in overview 'create new field'
I created a custom field type for drupal 10. If I want to use this field in an entity I go to 'Manage fields', then I have to click on 'Create a new field'. Then I get an overview of installed field types, including the one I created myself.
How can I change the corresponding icon in the code of my field type. The icon is a .svg file.

Individual field types don't have icons, only field type categories: https://www.drupal.org/node/3375748

But you can hack it by injecting very specific CSS for your type, e.g. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_field/-/blob/2.0.0/twig_field.module#L75

I probably used the wrong wording. I created a module with a new field type. It is a variant of the name module. When adding fields in a site, you get an overview of all installed field types, each having an icon, to choose from. With my field type comes a default icon that I want to replace with my own. I like to know how.

The wording you used was fine, @Hudri’s comment is still the right answer. Field types don’t have a setting for an icon, but you can use CSS to provide one

Thanks Hudri and Clive. I added now the hook_field_type_category_info_alter() in my module, updated my_module.libraries.yml, did add my_module.field_ui.css in /css and the svg in /image. All with replacing 'twig_field' by my_module name. But I must have forgotten something, since the icon doesn't appear.

I found why: my theme is blocking my svg. Thanks for your help.
